# Update syntax with condition in Sybase

Tags: sybase

I need to update a table with some condition but I don't know how to write the correct syntax for Sybase. Basically the update only run when country is NULL and either street1, street2 or street3 > 40.

```
 UPDATE myTable
     SET status = 'X',
       reason = 'Address is too long'     

       when IsNull(Country,' ') = ' ' and Street1 > 40 OR Street2 > 40
       OR Street3 > 40

 WHERE CatName = 'BB'
 AND userid = 258
 AND status = 'A'
```

Comment: You need parenthesis around your or's and in sybase you can do `Country is null` rather than filling null with a string and then comparing to empty string.

Comment: Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `when` logic into the `where` clause, eg:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET status = 'X',
        reason = 'Address is too long'     
WHERE CatName = 'BB'
AND   userid  = 258
AND   status  = 'A'
AND   Country is NULL
AND   (char_length(Street1) > 40 OR 
       char_length(Street2) > 40 OR 
       char_length(Street3) > 40)
```

Comment: I'm sorry by street1 > 40 I meant to say the length of street1: Len(street1) > 40? but applying this got me an error saying implicit conversion from datatype varchar to INT

Comment: updated answer with Sybase-ASE specific solution (`char_length(...)`); not sure if that'll work in SQLAnywhere, IQ or Advantage; not sure why `len(...)` did not work for you as `len()` is a valid ASE function ... would need to know your Sybase product and the actual text of your query attempt

Comment: I think our Sybase is ASE and the char_length() works. This is one of our oldest server that soon will be retired. Thank you!